# Transferring a list string values in datatime format

Tags: python

I have several datatime values that are listed as a string

```
s = ["19 Nov 2015 18:45:00.000","19 Nov 2015 18:45:00.000"]
```

Now i would like to convert them to a strptime format. With one single value I would have done it like this:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

However when I try this

```
results = [datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f") for s in results]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample19.py", line 5, in <module>
results = [datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in s]
TypeError: must be string, not list
```

Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: It seems like it runs a different line of code than what you've wrote. Save your source code file and try again

Comment: I think problem with your variable name, `s` used as list and variable to  iterating over list. Please change. It will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've simply got list comprehensions wrong.
Having this list

```
string_dates = ["19 Nov 2015 18:45:00.000", "19 Nov 2015 18:45:00.000"]
```

you convert it to `datetime` objects like so:

```
results = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f") for date in string_dates]
```

Your code didn't work because you passed `s` to strptime, when you meant to pass `i`. This is where good variable names come in handy

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be

```
results = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in s]
```

this will use the element and not the full list